# How to override, from extending class, inherited @MappedSuperclass @Column updatable and insertable attributes

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Given the following setup how do I make the inherited `producerId` field be `updatable = false, insertable = false` from within `Book`.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class StockItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "producer_id")
    private Integer producerId;

}

@Entity
public class Producer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private Integer name;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_item")
public class Book extends StockItem {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producer_id")
    private Producer producer;

    // make inherited producerId field updatable = false, insertable = false here

}
```

I specifically do NOT want to do the following as I need that property to stay updatable and insertable for other inheritors:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class StockItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "producer_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer producerId;

}
```

UPDATE: another constraint is that all classes extending the @MappedSuperclass represent the same table

Comment: Have you looked into @AttributeOverrides ?

Comment: @xerx593 See my posted answer, that's how I've dealt with it in the past but I don't like that solution as it generates more boilerplate and an antipattern in the override of 'setProductId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion by Asoub I did the following using `@AttributeOverride` and it works great as it allows modification of all column attributes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_item")
@AttributeOverride(
        name = "producerId",
        column = @Column(name = "producer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
)
public class Book extends StockItem {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producer_id")
    private Producer producer;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found is to set `producerId` inside `producer` setter but it's not an ideal solution.

```java
@Entity
public class Book extends StockItem {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "producer_id",  insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Producer producer;

    public void setProducer(Producer producer) {
        setProducerId(producer.getId());
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    /**
        Setting producerId here directly may cause inconsistency between producer and inherited producerId, therefore method is overridden to be unusable.
    */
    @Override
    public void setProducerId(Integer producerId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Inherited field producer cannot be set from Book");
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getProducerId() {
        return producer != null ? producer.getId() : null;
    }

}
```